# Deployment react native App in Computer Web Version

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, expo, cross-platform

I have react native app and i use expo like a connection to my android emulator.

[image: Structure]

I want to run project in my laptop, but when i try to do it, i get a simple white screen. No splash animation or errors in compiler.

[image: Libraries]

May i to create another dashboard/window for computer version? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my mind about creating web version, but there is one good guide : https://aureliomerenda.medium.com/create-a-native-web-app-with-react-native-web-419acac86b82